# Git Remote Server connections refused

Tags: git

I'm getting crazy with this error, after 2 days i didn't find what wrong in my system, and I'm sure that it is very easy to fix it.

When I try to connect to my git server using git functions I got the message:
**Unable to open connection:
Host does not exist
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

I will explain a little more:
If I open a gitBash (from my windows machine) and I try to connect to my git server (over Debian) using ssh everything is working fine. rsa autentification works fine and logins perfetly

For example:
**ssh myGitHost**

once in, I can go to **/opt/git/MyRep.git** and I can create repositories using **git init --bare**
also from my windows guibash I can use **scp** instructions and again works fine, so I can clone my local repositores and copy to my gitServer

BUT...

When I try to do any git action from my gitbash (clone or push) like
**git clone myGitHost:/opt/git/MyRep.git** 
I get that persisten error.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

I'm using putty (plink) in my windows machine after get the same error using openSSH
and at the git server i dind't install anything like gitlab, just git,

I found some issues talking about that but not one fix my problem becouse most of them talk about gitlab configurations or github problems connections.

Did I miss any daemon?
Or is needed any aditional software like gitlab?
Regard

Comment: Could you try using git clone ssh://myGitHost:/opt/git/MyRep.git ? I'm not sure if git defaults to using ssh, so that might be your problem.

You can also try doing a ssh -T myGitHost and see what that outputs.

Comment: I don't think you need the colon in the host address if you're not specifying the port. The colon is used to separate the host and path when using the git protocol (scp style syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

Just removing Putty and OpenSSH from the windows and after that generating a new rsa key with the internal ssh of gitbash.

I don't know exactly why, but now it's working well.

Regards